# CodeIgniter 4 Models preloading

Tags: php, codeigniter, oop, codeigniter-4

I am new to PHP OOP and CodeIgniter and I need help. I am using CodeIgniter 4 and trying to preload model logas_model in BaseController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

/**
 * Class BaseController
 *
 * BaseController provides a convenient place for loading components
 * and performing functions that are needed by all your controllers.
 * Extend this class in any new controllers:
 *     class Home extends BaseController
 *
 * For security be sure to declare any new methods as protected or private.
 *
 * @package CodeIgniter
 */

use App\Models\Admin\logas_model;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\RequestInterface;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BaseController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * An array of helpers to be loaded automatically upon
     * class instantiation. These helpers will be available
     * to all other controllers that extend BaseController.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $helpers = ['form', 'session', 'html', 'number'];
    protected $logas;

    /**
     * Constructor.
     */
    public function initController(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        // Do Not Edit This Line
        parent::initController($request, $response, $logger);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        // Preload any models, libraries, etc, here.
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        ///$this->session = \Config\Services::session();
        $this->logas = new logas_model();
    }

}
```

Model logas_model code:

```
<?php namespace App\Models\Admin;

use CodeIgniter\Model;
use Config\Services;

class logas_model extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'veiksmai_logs';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    protected $returnType = 'array';
    protected $useSoftDeletes = true;

    protected $useTimestamps = TRUE;
    protected $createdField = 'created_at';
    protected $updatedField = 'updated_at';
    protected $deletedField = 'deleted_at';

    protected $allowedFields = ['uid', 'veiksmas'];

    public function get_all_veiksmai()
    {
        return $this->select("CONCAT(`user`.`vardas`, ' ', `user`.`pavarde`) AS `user_vardas_pavarde`, `veiksmai_logs`.`veiksmas`, `veiksmai_logs`.`created_at`, `veiksmai_logs`.`id`")
            ->join('user', 'user.id = veiksmai_logs.uid')
            ->orderBy("`veiksmai_logs`.`created_at`", 'DESC')
            ->findAll();
    }

    public function add_veiksmas($veiksmas)
    {
        $session = Services::session()->get();

        $data = [
            'uid' => $session['uid'],
            'veiksmas' => $veiksmas
        ];
        return $this->insert($data);
    }
}
```

And then, in other controller, which extends Controller, I am trying to use that preloaded model by using it's function like this:

```
$this->logas->add_veiksmas('Created User.');
```

Full that Controller code:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Models\Admin\vartotojai_model;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Vartotojai extends Controller
{
    private $vartotojai;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->vartotojai = new vartotojai_model();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->logas->add_veiksmas('Created User.');

        $this->data['vartotojai'] = $this->vartotojai->get_all_vartotojai();
        echo view('templates/Admin/Header', ['title' => 'Vartotojai']);
        echo view('Admin/Vartotojai/Index', $this->data);
        echo view('templates/Admin/Footer');
    }
}
```

But it is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> Change **Controller**

```
class Vartotojai extends Controller
{
```

> into **BaseController**

```
    class Vartotojai extends BaseController
```

Answer (score 1):

That may be because you have not extended BaseController to Vartotojai controller.

class Vartotojai extends BaseController

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly note: whenever you are preloading(Models, helpers, libraries e.t.c), you need to extend the BaseController on all the controllers that will be using that model.In your case you preloaded the model correctly but you did not extend your controller to the BaseController. Use the below format in your controllers:

```
<?php
  namespace App\Controllers;
  use CodeIgniter\Controller;

  class ClassName extends BaseController
  {
    //your functions and code
  }
?>
```